# explode function doesn't work for me?

Tags: php

I want to change the string into array after using foreach() so 
          how is it done?

```
$g = "";
$changer = explode(",", $g);
foreach ($y as $key => $c) {
    foreach ($c['movie'] as $rr) {
        $g .= $rr->movieName . ",";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? g is empty and you're exploding it into what? http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: nothing I was hasty posting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, theres a much easier way to do it than what you're doing:

```
foreach ($y as $key => $c) {
    foreach ($c['movie'] as $rr) {
        $changer[] = $rr->movieName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself the only problem is the position of my explode function:

```
<!-- my code -->
$g ="";         
foreach ($y as $key => $c) {
    foreach ($c['movie'] as $rr) {
        $g .= $rr->movieName . ",";
    }
}
$changer = explode(",", $g);
```

Comment: I added my own answer since the way you're doing this is long winded and pointless.

Comment: and your answer is awesome thanks for the help then ^^